# m.find(...) == m.end() - which is used, iterator or const_iterator

Tags: c++, templates, stl

std::map find/end both provides const_iterator and iterator, e.g.

```
  iterator end ();
  const_iterator end () const
```

Out of curiosity,if I have a std::map , which will be called/compared here, an iterator or a const_iterator ? :

```
if(m.find(key) != m.end()) {
   ...
}
```

And should I care ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `m` is `const`, then a `const_iterator` will be returned; otherwise an `iterator` will be returned.

If all you are doing is testing for existence of an element in the map, then it doesn't really matter which one is used.

Comment: It matters when you write you own algorithm. Then you should specify whether your algorithm is a modifying algorithm. It if isn't then you're saying it works with `const_iterator`. It's also a good idea to know which algorithms you call are modifying and which aren't: this way when you get an error you can tell it's because you passed a `const_iteratr` (perhaps because it comes from a `const` object) to a modifying algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if your map is const or not.  If it is, you'll get a const_iterator.  If not, you get an iterator.